# Angular ui-router override directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I'm trying to override `uiSref` from `ui.router`.
This is how I'm doing it now:

```
angular.module("dependencies", [
    "ui.router",
    "ui.bootstrap"
]);
```

I have a parent module called `dependencies` where I inject `ui.router` and other
And here I'm trying to override the `uiSref` directive setting the priority to 100:

```
angular.module('ui.router.state').directive('uiSref', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    };
}]);

var app = angular.module("app", ["dependencies"]);
```

But doesn't work, can point what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. You can check [my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2jGRcXMvP7XvIs4w6GWl?p=preview) with the same code where it works.

```
angular.module('app', ['dependencies']);

angular.module('dependencies', ['ui.router']);

angular.module('ui.router.state')
    .directive('uiSref', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 100,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.text('uiSref override invoked...');
            }
        };
    }]);
```

I'd change the approach though - a better way to override things in AngularJs is by using [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators).